# How to customize log format in git?

Tags: git

I want to customize the log format in git, such that it will only show the comment and the person who have commited the code..

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following in your alias block in `.git/config`

```
lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

Comment: Git has format tools pretty =format , then use any of this Option as  in ans. It will show you information in that way.  Alias is for not type log command every time.
%H  Commit hash
%h  Abbreviated commit hash
%T  Tree hash
%t  Abbreviated tree hash
%P  Parent hashes
%p  Abbreviated parent hashes
%an Author name
%ae Author e-mail
%ad Author date (format respects the --date= option)
%ar Author date, relative
%cn Committer name
%ce Committer email
%cd Committer date
%cr Committer date, relative
%s  Subject